# Is is possible to get information of .class file(in java) without use of reflection

Tags: java, reflection

can someone guide me?

Is it possible to get information of .class file (in java) without the use of reflection? Information like class methods,constructors fields etc., and also can we invoke them without using Reflection in Java?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like homework. Retag the question, if so.

Comment: Why don't you want to use reflection here? This is precisely what it was made for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can analyize the `.class` in terms of bytecode. Either manually or using a library like [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/)

Answer (score 2):

See Java Virtual Machine Spec, Chapter 4 *The class File Format*.

Comment: The information this chap reveal, is about how a class file format is taken and understand by the COMPILER/JVM.It doesn;t revela how to invoke them ??

Comment: @zaree you can't "invoke" format. As pointed out in the other answer here, you need to write library to read .class files according to format described in spec. Or, if you don't want to write such tool yourself, use BCEL.